# Inserting unicode escape sequence data to SQL server db (pyodbc)

Tags: sql-server, unicode, pyodbc, freetds

I'm trying to insert data I scraped from the web into an SQL server db, and the relevant columns of my db table are set up as `nvarchar(max)` type.

Testing this in a python shell:

```
dbargs={'DATABASE': '<mydbname>',
 'DRIVER': '{FreeTDS}',
 'PORT': '1433',
 'PWD': '<mypass>',
 'SERVER': '<server>',
 'UID': '<myusername>'}

import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(**dbargs)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

insert_cmd="INSERT INTO c_master (run_id, product_name) VALUES (?,?)"
```

Then

```
cursor.execute(insert_cmd, (274, u'test naméâôóòöë'))
```

works fine, however

```
cursor.execute(insert_cmd, (274, u'test \u2019d'))
```

causes the error

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I find that I am scraping data of the latter type and generating errors when I try to insert it as above into the db in my writer pipeline.

What is the correct way to handle such data?

(I'm using FreeTDS, unixodbc, MSSQL Server, pyodbc)

**FreeTDS and unixodbc conf:**

/etc/odbc.init:

```
[myserver]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description =Myserver MSSQL database
# Servername corresponds to the section in freetds.conf
Servername=myserver
Database = mydbname
TDS_Version = 7.0
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/odbcsql.log
ForceTrace = Yes
Pooling = Yes

[FreeTDS]
Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout = 120 
CPReuse =
```

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf:

```
[global]
tds version = 7.0


dump file = /var/log/freetds.log
debug flags = 0xffff

# timeout = 10
# connect timeout = 10

text size = 64512


[myserver]
host = <myserverip>
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
dump_file = /var/log/freetds.log
client charset = UTF-8
```

I also added TDSDUMP="/var/log/freetds.log" to /etc/environment and /etc/profile. Although weirdly, I'm still not seeing the freetds log.

Comment: Howdy, a few questions. Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? To properly use Unicode, you're going to have to also pass along the `TDS_Version` to the connection string - are you doing that in a DSN definition?

Comment: Python 2.7. I set TDS_Versionin /etc/odbc.ini. I'll update my question to include these confs now.

Comment: Looking at the /tmp/freetds.log seems to show version 4.2 despite my configuration. I guess this might be the issue! Any ideas why my conf isn't giving me version 7.0?

Comment: @FlipperPA I also find that if I pass "TDS_Version" to the connection string as you say, it works! So clearly my freetds conf is just being ignored or is broken?

Comment: I've submitted as an answer with some more information on TDS versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `TDS_Version` as part of the connection string. You're connecting with a full connection string, which bypasses the DSN if you pass the full server name as SERVER in the `connect()` declaration. If you want to connect with a DSN, you need to provide a `DSN` (and `UID` / `PWD`) rather than `SERVER` and `PORT`.

I've issued a pull request to better explain TDS Versions to FreeTDS here: https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/pull/71

The default version of TDS used if it isn't provided doesn't support Unicode (as you saw!). Assuming you're using SQL Server 2005 or newer, if you're using:

- FreeTDS 1.0: use TDS_Version 7.4
- FreeTDS 0.95: use TDS_Version 7.3
- FreeTDS 0.91: use TDS_Version 7.2

Good luck!

Comment: I understand what you say about bypassing the DSN, but why doesn't it respect the global freedns.conf "tds version"?

Comment: That's a good question; I honestly don't know, but I suspect it only hits the file if you're using DSNs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to configure your FreeTDS connection to recognize the client encoding that will be used for your insert statements.

In ODBC there is no way that I know of to declare an encoding for individual parameters.  All SQL text and character data are interpreted according a single client-encoding connection configuration.

You might also set the [TDSDUMP](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/logging.htm) environment parameter, and look at the data sent to your server.  If you don't get that far, try the ODBC log.

Comment: Well my freetds conf is setup as version 7.0 and client charset = UTF-8. Like I said, most unicode is handled by default, it just seems to be unicode escape sequences like `u'\u2019'`

Comment: So then I think it's a Python thing: that "unicode literals" do not define strings encoded as UTF-8.  If you explicitly convert your literal to a Unicode type of that encoding, all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem everything was working fine and the only issue was that there were "?" characters in the table after insert statement. I am using Python 3.7.2.

So finally it worked when I used similar to following query.

```
insert_cmd="""INSERT INTO c_master (run_id, product_name) VALUES ('{runId}',N'{productName}')""".format(runId=4, productName='حلواہ پوری')
```

Comment: This could lead to a SQL injection, if you are not careful with the parameters to `format`